# Validating scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I'm still new to C and am trying to validate an input from the user. It has to be in the form of 'C' int int int or 'L' int int int int. They can also enter as many as they want. I test the first character and then take the 3 or 4 following intergers - These are used to make some structures in other functions. The bit that I can't get to work is the else at the bottom. I want it to reject any "types" that aren't l/L/c/C

So far I have

```
   counter = 0 ;
   while ( type != '\n' )
   {  

      scanf("%c", &type) ;
      if ( type == 'L' || type == 'l')
      {
         scanf(" %d %d %d %d", &llx, &lly, &urx, &ury) ;
         Line line = makeline(llx,lly,urx,ury) ;
         shape = makeshapeline( line ) ;
         box = makeboxshape( shape ) ;
         counter++ ;
      }
      else if ( type == 'C' || type == 'c')
      {
         scanf(" %d %d %d", &x, &y, &rad) ;
         Circle circle = makecircle(x, y, rad) ;
         shape = makeshapecircle( circle ) ;
         box = makeboxshape( shape ) ;
         counter++ ;
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Invalid input\n") ;
         return 0 ;
      }

      if (counter == 1) 
      {
         boxfinal = box ; //On the first run initialise the final box to the first result
      }  

      if (counter > 1)
      {
         boxfinal = makeboxbox( box, boxfinal) ;
      }
   }
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Start by checking the return result of [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). It is well documented, and reports the number of *successful* parameters parsed. Once you know your params were parsed, then range/value check them. And get into that habit, because without exceptions, the C language standard library is *very* return-value oriented for success for failure.

Comment: how about an MIT licensed library that does it?  Here is the exact line: http://git.netsurf-browser.org/libsvgtiny.git/tree/src/svgtiny.c#n932 and http://git.netsurf-browser.org/libsvgtiny.git/tree/src/svgtiny.c#n708 ... netsurf has some pretty decent code to learn from.

Comment: Suggest change `scanf("%c", &type)` to `scanf(" %c", &type)`.  Add space.

Comment: Note: spaces in `" %d %d %d"` are not needed.

Comment: Your `scanf("%c", &type)` is getting the `\n` from a _previous_ line like "C 1 2 3\n" and that exists your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider `scanf`ing with a `%s` instead of `%c` and then parse the resulting string.  The reason is that `scanf("%s", str)` will ignore whitespace automatically, but `scanf("%c", char)` will return whitespace characters like `\n`, which you don't want.

Edit: as a more general note, as was mentioned in some comments already, you don't need to worry about inserting whitespace in the `scanf` family of functions if you are only extracting strings, integers, and floats (and maybe something I'm forgetting), as these functions all ignore whitespace in the input string when extracting these data types.  (An extracted string will always be whitespace-free unless otherwise specified by the user.)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest `fgets()/sscanf()`

```
char buf[100];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
  if (4 == sscanf(buf, "%*1[Ll]%d%d%d%d", &llx, &lly, &urx, &ury) {
    do_line();
  else if (3 == sscanf(buf, "%*1[Cc]%d%d%d", &x, &y, &rad) {
    do_circle();
  else
    do_Invalid_input();
}
```